# Почему конфликтует код?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Делаю маску для текстового поля, и делаю проверку при воде в это поле : но почему-то работает только один код 
этот

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

//mask_form   

    // работает либо эта строка
      $("#phone").mask(" +38-(099)-999-99-99");
     // либо эта
      $(".telephone").on('input', function () {

      alert("Привет.")

      });

});
```

вот код библиотеки которую я использую для маски : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/25/

Возможно проблема из-за конфликта с ней? Но ошибок никаких нету.

Comment: Пример нерабочего кода тоже привести нужно, иначе непонятно в чем проблема.

Comment: @Дмитрий Заварзин дополнил вопрос

Comment: А что должно произойти при выполнении mask?

Comment: @ Artie Lay код приводиться к виду : "+38-(099)-999-99-99" где  где девятки это цифры которые можно заменить а остальные , нельзя. То-есть авто форматирование поля

Comment: проблема в том, что в плагине `function keypressEvent(e) {...}` возвращает `false` (что значит не надо обрабатывать событие дальше). Если вернуть `true`, то маска с вашим `alert`'ом работать не будет. Т.е. надо каким-то образом забиндить ваше действие так, чтобы оно отрабатывалось до срабатывания плагина

Comment: @BOPOH подскажите нубу как такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в следующем: используемый плагин подписывается на события `keydown` / `keypress`, а вы подписываетесь на `input`

[Здесь](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) описан порядок вызова этих событий:

> > Typically keypress will fire, then the typed charater will appear in the text area, then input will fire

Таким образом получаем, что сначала на ввод символа должен реагировать плагин, а потом уже ваш код (т.к. `keypress` срабатывает раньше чем `input`).

Но здесь есть одна особенность: плагин на ввод символа возвращает `false` (см. функцию `keypressEvent` плагина). Таким образом все связанные события не срабатывают, в том числе и ваш `input`

Но т.к. текст `input`'а все-таки меняется, то срабатывает событие `change`, на которое вы можете подписаться.

Т.е. чтобы исправить вашу проблему, надо либо подписываться на `keydown` / `keypress` (и расположить ваш код до инициализации маски), либо подписываться на `change` (но он вызывается когда `input` теряет фокус)

Answer (score 1):

Этот код устанавливает действие при загрузке страницы, оно может быть одно.

наверное, Вы хотели написать вот это:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#phone").mask(" +38-(099)-999-99-99");
  $(".telephone").on('input', function () {

  });
});
```

Comment: нет проблема не в этом( так уже пробовал решить. Скорее всего конфликт идёт с библиотекой которую я использовал , чтоб сделать маску, но ошибок не выдает , по этому не знаю, что исправлять ... Возможно как-то можно экранировать код?

Comment: Загрузка может быть одна, но подписаться на загрузку (как и на любое другое событие) можно много раз

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#phone").mask(" +38-(099)-999-99-99");
  $(document).on("input", ".telephone", function () {

  });
});
```

Если не сработает, тогда попробуйте слушать событие keydown или keypress

Comment: Блин когда событие заменил на "change" то код заработал ? Так чтож получается , что код библиотеки как - то не дает мне пользоваться событием input ? Подскажите возможно ли это исправить как-то ?