# подсчитать слова в поле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я сделал выбор дней с календаря используя datepicker. Помечая дни на календарике - дата записывается в инпут через зяпятую.

```
<input type="text" id="altField" value="2015-09-25, 2015-09-26">
```

Все в порядке. Работает, но я захотел, что бы еще отображалось внизу количество выбранных дней. С помощью `lenght` решил посчитать количество слов, типо дней.

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

    function dayCount( val ){
        return {
            days: val.match(/\S+/g).length
        }
    }

    var $div = $('#result');

    $('#altField').on('input', function(){
        var c = dayCount( this.value );
        $div.html(
            "<br>Дней: "+ c.days
        );
    });

</script>
```

Но не работает. Допустим если я с клавиатуры ввожу слова(даты) или копирую в поле ввода, то считает прекрасно, но если значение попадает туда из календарика его будто не замечает. Что делать? :(

Comment: на `change` подписывайтесь, тогда будете ловить изменения. [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445236/5079) я немного описывал как работают события

Comment: пробовал по всякому добавлять change, но тогда у меня вообще никак не реагирует. ни с клавы ни с календарика

Comment: вписал все возможные значения что нагуглил bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function() реагирует на клавиатуру, и на клик мышкой в поле ввода после того как там значения с календарика оказываются... просто после выбора даты все равно не реагирует :(

Comment: Когда вы ручками меняете значение, то `change` вызывается когда элемент теряет фокус. Но вы же через js меняете элемент? С ним немного сложнее - change срабатывает только когда вы в браузере элемент меняете. Когда меняете его через js, надо самому бросать событие. Например так: `var elem = $('#elem-id'); elem.val('123').change();`

Comment: ура! спасибо, что объяснили, получилось!! :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы ручками меняете значение, то `change` вызывается когда элемент теряет фокус. Но вы же через js меняете элемент? С ним немного сложнее - `change` срабатывает только когда вы в браузере элемент меняете. Когда меняете его через js, надо самому бросать событие. Например так:

```
var elem = $('#elem-id'); elem.val('123').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще через пробел указывать все события, на которые нужно реагировать. Вот так:

```
$('#altField').on('input change keyup', function () {});
```

Кроме того, есть такая полезная библиотека [jQuery text change custom event](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event). Помимо основных событий, вроде change, она умеет реагировать на события вставки из буфера и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Можете `Old-school`'но использовать `var x = myVar.split(delimiter); console.log(x.length)` для подсчета слов